# Xcode build failed: could not find or load main class

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm trying to upload my file it showing me this error after I update xcode to 12.5

> **App Store Connect Operation Error**
> Could not find or load main class
> Tucker.Library.Java.Extensions:.Library.Java.Extensions:.Network.Library.Java.Extensions:.System.Library.Java.Extensions:.usr.lib.java:.

[image: Image of the error, titled "Distribution failed with errors:"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

Go to:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/bin

You'll find:
iTMSTransporter

This is simply a build script so open it up in your favorite text editor (I like VisualStudio).

Change this line:
JVM_LIB_PATH="-Djava.library.path=${ESCAPED_WOA_TOP_LEVEL}/macOS/lib:${HOME}/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:."

To this:
JVM_LIB_PATH="-Djava.library.path="${ESCAPED_WOA_TOP_LEVEL}"/macOS/lib:"${HOME}"/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:."

Basically just add four backslash-escaped quotes around ${ESCAPED_WOA_TOP_LEVEL} and ${HOME}.

Enjoy successful Xcode uploads again!!

:)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665287